# how to change tag a href in wordpress for validator w3

Tags: wordpress, w3c, w3c-validation

i my website is thai language, and link in webpage is thai

i check page in https://validator.w3.org/  it's show error "Bad value for attribute href on element a: Percentage ("%") is not followed by two hexadecimal digits."

Sample : [https://dev.dmr.go.th/%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8…B8%/"](https://dev.dmr.go.th/%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%E2%80%A6B8%/%22)

i use wordpress for my site.how to fix this url to be correct?

Thank you

Fix url in thai to be correct in https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: In your URL some characters are [URL encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP):  Each encoded character start with a `%` followed by 2 hexadecimal digits, so something like`%EO`. The error seems to be related to the end of your URL that finish with `%/` and should be finishing without the `%`as *"it is not followed by two hexadecimal digits"*.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you for your reply . My some url working but some url error. i go to post edit page and delete old url and click update again. it's working. but my website a lot post.  i want to reset permalink for post but not it's not reset. how to regenerate permalink for post  same delete old url and update in backend?

Comment: First make a backup of your database. Try the following: Go to WordPress settings > Permalinks. Then change temporarily of permalink structure, choosing something different. Then save. Then Select back your original permalink structure and Save. I hope that it will solve your issue.